# Problema de salto de linea powershell 5

Tags: powershell, windows-server

Tengo esta línea, la cual me escribe en un archivo de texto, el problema es que me sobrescribe la misma línea, y yo quiero que me ponga todo línea por línea.

```
1..100 | % { $ping.send(“10.1.5.$_”) | select address, status, name | Write-Output > archivo.txt}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es quitar el **Write-Output** del *foreach*, porque al filtrar en el pipeline con un select, cada entrada que quieras registrar se va a guardar como una tabla individual (encabezados y datos), para que puedas registrar mejor el resultado tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
1..100 | % { $ping.send(“10.1.5.$_”) | select address, status, name}  | Write-Output > archivo.txt
```

Y así tendrías en el archivo algo como esto:

```
address      status   name
-------      ------   ----
10.1.5.1      xxxx     xxx       
10.1.5.2      xxxx     xxx       
10.1.5.3      xxxx     xxx
```